# EF Core 5 migrations - update composite primary and foreign keys

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am using EF Core code first migrations. I have two tables (models), `TableA` has 4 columns which are set as composite primary key and `TableB` has the same 4 columns set as primary key and foreign key to `TableA`.

On of the four columns is of type int and I need to change it to long. I changed the type to long in both models and added a new migration. However, I am getting the following error when trying to update the database to apply the migration:

> The object 'PK_TableA' is dependent on column 'Number'.
>
> The object 'FK_TableB_TableA_Column1_Column2_Column3_Column4' is dependent on column 'Number'.
>
> ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN Number failed because one or more objects access this column.

The column `Number` (column #3) in the error above is the one which has the type of int.

The generated migration is as follows:

```cs
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<long>(
        name: "Number",
        table: "TableA",
        type: "bigint",
        nullable: false,
        oldClrType: typeof(int),
        oldType: "int");

    migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<long>(
        name: "Number",
        table: "TableB",
        type: "bigint",
        nullable: false,
        oldClrType: typeof(int),
        oldType: "int");
}
```

I checked a number of topics here but none of them includes a solution for a "composite primary and foreign keys".

I found [this article](https://www.pmichaels.net/tag/alter-table-alter-column-id-failed-because-one-or-more-objects-access-this-column/) about manually changing the generated migration code. But I am not sure if it s going to work with a composite primary and foreign key. Or, if it is the right way to fix this issue.

Any advise will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone was looking for an answer to this question, this is how I solved the issue.

I edited the generated migration code, as follows, to manually remove the foreign key first in `TableB` and then the two composite primary keys in `TableA` and `TableB` and then added them after changing the column type to `bigint` (according to the generated migration code):

```cs
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
  migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
    name: "FK_TableB",
    table: "TableB");

  migrationBuilder.DropPrimaryKey(
    name: "PK_TableA",
    table: "TableA");

  migrationBuilder.DropPrimaryKey(
    name: "PK_TableB",
    table: "TableB");

  migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<long>(
    name: "Number",
    table: "TableA",
    type: "bigint",
    nullable: false,
    oldClrType: typeof(int),
    oldType: "int");

  migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<long>(
    name: "Number",
    table: "TableB",
    type: "bigint",
    nullable: false,
    oldClrType: typeof(int),
    oldType: "int");

  migrationBuilder.AddPrimaryKey(
    name: "PK_TableA",
    table: "TableA",
    columns: new[] { "Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4" });

  migrationBuilder.AddPrimaryKey(
    name: "PK_TableB",
    table: "TableB",
    columns: new[] { "Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4" });

  migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
    name: "FK_TableB",
    table: "TableB",
    columns: new[] { "Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4" },
    principalTable: "TableA",
    principalColumns: new[] { "Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4" },
    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
}
```

The same code was added for the `Down` method.